# Resizing Mouse Shape changed in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, csplitterwnd

I have ported my application to be built with Visual Studio 2013. 
After building it, I found that the resizing mouse shape is interchanged.

[image]

The first shape of mouse pointer appears when I want to resize a vertical splitter and the second one appears when I want to resize a horizontal splitter: this behavior is new. In the previous release of my tool, the first one appears when I want to resize a horizontal splitter and the second one appears when I want to resize a vertical splitter.

I didn't change anything in the code. How can I make it to reproduce the old behavior?

Comment: That shouldn't change by itself as a result of porting the project. Go through *.rc file (or *.rc2 file), find the reference to cursor file (something like "resize_north_south.cur"), show what's in there and how the cursor is loaded.

Comment: There is no reference for it in my rc files!

Answer (score 0):

We found that we use a third party MFC libraries and we use the cursors from them; in the new release, they have swapped the names of the icons of the cursors and this is the root cause of this problem. As a workaround, we have swapped the names to give the old behavior.